# Como conectase a SQL Server desde un archivo .json

Tags: sql-server, json

Buen dia Estoy intentando conectarme a SQL Server desde un archivo JSON.
Soy nuevo en este lenguaje. Me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi codigo es el siguiente :

```
 {
   "databaseConnections":[
    {
      "hostname":"GDJNT421\SQLFF4",
      "username":"ffreporting",
      "password":"reporting2k8"
    }
    ]
  }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El erro es por que no puedes usar ese **slash**, prueba de la siguiente manera

```
{
 "databaseConnections":
 [
   {
     "hostname":"GDJNT421\\SQLFF4",
     "username":"ffreporting",
     "password":"reporting2k8"
   }
 ]
}
```

**usa doble \** para escapar el carácter

Comment: ya intente eso y aun sigue apareciendo el error.

Comment: Es correcto. Gracias @omargt8

Comment: De nada bro, sigue adelante!